# SQL link server to server with a host name

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to link database servers and I noticed that one is named:  `test_host\test_database`. When I make the link, I can't query it. I get a log in failure timeout. In area configuration remote and local connections are enabled.

Also SQL Server Express won't allow me to enter an IP address.

So how would I link to this server?

Comment: What do you get if you right-click the linked server and choose "Test connection"?  Assuming you're using SSMS or a similar utility.

Comment: I do not have a test connection option or ssms. I am using SQL Express 2005 so a lot of features are missing. Connecting to a host name with a database after it (with a slash) shouldnt be a problem??

Comment: IS there a way to access it via IP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alias. Create this on the machine and it worked. Need it for those tricky machines that are behind different domains.